# Unable to uninstall Fody Costura

Tags: fody, fody-costura

We used Fody Costura to pack a complex WPF application. Now, we want to uninstall it because  of the huge size of the resulting executable.

We deleted the nuget-packages (Fody, Fody-Costura) from all assemblies and deleted all bin and obj folders. After building with Visual Studio, the Weavers.xml is automatically restored and the exe is packed.

I already reinstalled and deinstalled the nuget-packages again, no effect. I did "Search in Files" for "Costura" and "Fody" in the sources folder, no hit.

How can uninstall it?

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that the cause of the issue was a referenced library (which was actually an .NET executable), that also used Fody.Costura.
Bringing that reference into my application, it seems the post-injection of Fody also injected my assembly.
By removing the referencing assembly, everything works fine now.